# Speed Loss Using Google Wifi and managed switch for Centurylink fiber

Tags: networking, router, modem, switch, fiber

I replaced the Centurylink “modem/router” with Google Wi-Fi and a managed switch using the instructions on this post:

https://superuser.com/a/1186991/793565

All went well, and I was able to access the internet once I set up the PPPoE on the Google Wi-Fi main point unit and VLAN tagging on the switch. However, my down/up speeds were decimated. Was getting 700-900 down and 800-950 up when using the Centurylink unit (ZyXEL C2100Z), but now getting anywhere from 50-100 down and 5-100 up. Followed instructions to set up the TP-Link switch (24 port version) with no issues once I manually set my up address and subnet properly on my MacBook Pro.

The only thing I can think of that may be causing an issue is that after everything was set up, I ran a separate Cat6 line from the LAN port on the Google Wi-Fi unit back into port 3 on the same switch which also has all my other Google Wi-Fi units hardwired in as well as other clients around the house (Ethernet wired into the house).  Admittedly, I am way out of my depth now. Do I need to use a separate switch for distribution around the house?  If so, I’ll need to get the little 5 port managed switch for the VLAN tagging needed to access the fiber and use the larger switch for distribution via the LAN port on the main Google Wi-Fi unit.

If that isn’t my issue, then I’m stumped. I had hoped I wouldn’t see any loss of bandwidth when eliminating the ZyXEL box. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.