# How can I achieve gigbit speeds upload and download with century link fiber and google nest wifi?

Tags: networking, router, wifi-configuration, vlan, fiber

I have read a lot about how to use alternate routers with CenturyLink Fiber and got myself the Google Nest Wifi.  I am using a TP-Link TL-SG105E switch for vlan straight from my ONT and then to my Google Nest Wifi.

The problem is that I am getting the correct download ~700 Mbps but am never getting above 100 Mbps for upload.  These results are the same for both LAN and WAN.

This is the other post that I referenced when setting up my devices: [How to Ditch CenturyLink Fiber "Modem"](https://superuser.com/questions/1148268/how-to-ditch-centurylink-fiber-modem)

Is there some settings that I am missing that is creating this bottleneck?

Comment: Have you tested the individual components of your network with iperf/jperf? I'm curious if it's the switch pooping out on you. Although if these speeds are through wifi that's likely the culprit.

Comment: I'll have to do that tonight and will update. This is all through LAN.

Comment: @NathanSaunders Also try a known good CAT6 cable between the TP-Link and Nest router, and if that doesn't result with >100mbit/s, try a different port on the TP-Link, as that sounds like either a port or cable issue dropping one of the twisted pairs _(of which is required for 1gbit/s throughput)_

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar issue (https://superuser.com/q/1510083/209800) although my download is not quite as good and my upload is a little better.